# How do I use seekdir/telldir in Golang?

Tags: go

I need to walk a filesystem in Golang and need to be able to resume scanning after restarting.

In C, I can do this via `telldir()` and then a `seekdir()` while resuming.

Golang only offers a `filepath.Walk()` function but that provides no way to start walking  the filesystem from a specific path or point.

This makes it inefficient for large filesystems

Any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

The signature for `filepath.walk` is:

```
func Walk(root string, walkFn WalkFunc) error
```

The documentation states that it starts at the directory specified by `root` and the signature of the callback function (`walkFn`) is:

```
type WalkFunc func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error
```

So you can start your scan at any given directory and walk the filesystem with that as the root. You cannot start part-way through a directory, but you can selectively prune the tree that you are walking.

There's also a "magic" return value, `filepath.SkipDir`, which skips either walking a directory (if returned when the callback is invoked on a directory) or the remaining files i the directory (if returned when the callback is invoked on a file).

This MAY be enough to get the behaviour that you want, but it is a little hard to tell from your question. You cannot break out of a `filepath.Walk` invocation, then resume it later on. However, you may be able to work around that limitation by spawning goroutines from within your `walkFn` callback, if you're mainly concerned with the callback taking time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your own state machine:
1- Walk all the way through using `filepath.Walk()` and buffer the result, then use this buffer with state (fast).

2- save the `root string` for the paused state, then scan from the ground up until you reach the saved path (slow).

3- You may use channels, like this working sample:
(try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wzygCwtyU2)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var dirs = make(chan string, 10)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go GetDirectories(`../`, `*`)
    fmt.Println()

    fmt.Println(<-dirs)
    fmt.Println(<-dirs)

    fmt.Println()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // pause

    for dir := range dirs {
        fmt.Println(dir)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(`Done.`)
}

// Returns the names of the subdirectories (including their paths)
// that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory.
func GetDirectories(root, pattern string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer close(dirs)
    filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, fi os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !fi.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        matched, err := filepath.Match(pattern, fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !matched {
            return nil
        }
        dirs <- path //dirs = append(dirs, path)
        return nil
    })
}
```